# Valid characters in cookie string?

Tags: http, cookies

Is this cookie string valid? Specifically this bit `I0=; []scayt_verLang=6;` I cant find a simple breakdown on the spec or an online validator.

```
Cookie  JavascriptEnabled=true; Cms_User_Id=removed6CYjfBVknUjmvf9Pp/uSVYoemoQOXCcB0SOg3kZWX9/KZfo9v5C8O7MmLg1Xz0qXf94Wf86p4rLi2lxxminXfnP/16p6pzmwIU5qz7Of4plcQkK6JM6XiU/zbyZb3gksDOz2s8xjhfzWg0ekjgTZUx76/kFuW10/Rf7O8n05aIZzhUX0Gd9UNjk40zLA1DkJ02uNGtMbnil9P9iqVARhE0CNjCZFxc9qoLpyyRXtqG8nv0V/3k175KXzzg6iW6j9jH/DuGH8ko5YZoo6TxiIcW3ViRnFVfoiMK49iatauD2nF6xOtRV6LLH57RV3DhkhTTb/MQurw8bHYbsZWJRIuSnFwKeFUEOoxvRG4friI6d4Qug11F1oM3ECSdbDeKKPXuq5+IUImt8XXZUtBFUeakqWT4oXgnsToeNoI0=; []scayt_verLang=6; ASP.NET_SessionId=removed0l4mhioft0uavblzdeq; last_msg_check=1425606361000
```

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Your example is missing a colon, it should be `Cookie:  JavascriptEnabled=true; ...`

Comment: Ah, sorry that was copie straight from dev tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie and Set-Cookie HTTP headers are defined in [RFC 6265 Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4) with [RFC 2616 Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) providing the basic types.

```
cookie-header = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                    ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                    ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                    ; and backslash
token             = <token, defined in [RFC2616], Section 2.2>
```

Token as defined in RFC 2616...

```
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                 (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                 | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                 | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                 | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```

Let's look at your cookie (I've stripped out most of the junk).

`JavascriptEnabled=true; Cms_User_Id=removedlotsoftextI0=; []scayt_verLang=6; ASP.NET_SessionId=removed0l4mhioft0uavblzdeq; last_msg_check=1425606361000`

You have a bunch of cookie-pairs...

- JavascriptEnabled=true
- Cms_User_Id=removedlotsoftextI0=
- []scayt_verLang=6
- ASP.NET_SessionId=removed0l4mhioft0uavblzdeq
- last_msg_check=1425606361000

The cookie-name `[]scayt_verLang` is invalid because it contains separators which are not allowed in a token.

`I0=` is not its own pair, but the tail end of the very long value of `Cms_User_Id`.  `=` is allowed in a `cookie-value` so it's valid.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I started to read through that RFC but didn't get that far.